# Problems with corrplot size

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I try to use the `corrplot` package to produce correlation matrix. I run this code:

```
library(corrplot)
alc_cor_plot <- cor(alc_cor[, -c(1,2)])
corrplot(alc_cor_plot, method = "ellipse")
```

But the labels appears to be very small. How do I adjust label size and make them larger?

Comment: You can adjust label size in the call to `corrplot()` by setting `tl.cex` (variable names) and `cl.cex` (legend labels) to larger numbers. See [the documentation](http://127.0.0.1:31713/library/corrplot/html/corrplot.html) for more information about the defaults.

Comment: @ulfelder The problem is the plot it is very small. How to make it bigger.

Comment: [This](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-November/042222.html) might help with that problem.

Comment: @ulfelder. The problem is when I plot it appears to be too small. How to increase the size of correlation matrix?

Comment: It's impossible to help more without being able to reproduce your work, which I can't do without your data or a toy data set that also gives you the same problem.

Comment: @ulfelder. Please see it. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z47v0mrhimzgucu/Rplot.png?dl=0)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to click on a link. Too risky.

Comment: When I plot it the size of the plot is very small how to increase it.

Comment: What is the dimension of your data `dim(alc_cor)`?

Comment: @ Robert. 1222 rows   18 columns. The problem is that I dont know why this is happen. When I try this with mtcars dataset everything is ok. But with my real data I fail. If you want see my link.

Comment: How to increase plotting area?

Comment: I fix the problem. The names of variables are very long but now when I add title it is not fix to centre, how to do it?